# TDD: Does EF Core In Memory Provider validates referential constraints?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, tdd, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.0

I'm really excited about in memory feature of EF Core for unit testing. It relieves  me of the burden to write dedicated repository, just for the sake of making code unit testable. But merely in memory testing in a collection wont't suffice.

> Does EF Core In Memory Provider validates referential constraints?

Comment: If you need validation of referential constraints, try [Testing with SQLite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/sqlite), which have "in memory" feature as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does EF Core In Memory Provider validates referential constraints?

The answer is: No.

**InMemory** provider is not a replacement for relational database. It is created for testing purpose.

Excerpt from the [documenation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/miscellaneous/testing/in-memory#inmemory-is-not-a-relational-database):

> **InMemory** is designed to be a general purpose database for testing, and
>   is not designed to mimic a relational database.
>   Some examples of this include:
>
> - **InMemory** will allow you to save data that would violate referential
>     integrity constraints in a relational database.
> - If you use `DefaultValueSql(string)` for a property in your model, this
>     is a relational database API and will have no effect when running
>     against **InMemory**.

The first point spot that any constraint is not validated by the provider.